# Websites not loading on Ubuntu with different browsers

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, konqueror

Outlook.com is not loading after login in Chrome, Konqueror, and Firefox -- only see a blank page after login.  I tried a clean install of Ubuntu and other Linux distributions (Fedora, Debian, Mint) but same issue is occurring.

What can cause Outlook.com not to load in Linux, yet same machine when booted to Window 7 loads site normally?  Is anyone else seeing the same problem?

Comment: if you already tried with multiple distros then this should not be Ubuntu issue. I dont have any issue with outlook.com on my browsers. Next thing you might want to check is your network.

Comment: If this also happens with other websites then it can be a network issue like Aizuddin Zali said. ('Outlook.com is not loading after login...' sounds like you might have switched to `https`)

Comment: If it is a network issue why does this not occur on same computer when booted with Windows OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems issue was caused by bug in Tenda W1801R router firmware.  (Strange it was affecting Linux clients only.)

I re-flashed with Tenda firmware (several version) but issue continued.  Finally, flashed with Advanced Tomato firmware and issue is no longer occurring.